# Can we use Eclipse IDE such that we can perform auto runs everyday without intervention? The scripts are selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, server, automation, cucumber

So I'm running automation scripts for the past few weeks and I noticed that these scripts don't require manual intervention, I just have to click on run that's all, So I was thinking whether it could be possible to auto run the scripts everyday without any intervention, like a batch run or something like that?

I'm using Eclipse IDE and the scripts are in selenium java with cucumber

I tried manual runs and I was expecting something like auto run everyday without the need to click on run every time

Comment: you can just build the jar or executable and set that to run as a scheduled task.  (or "CRON" for linux?)

Comment: I want it to be in such a way that it should run everyday by itself and send me a mail for detailing the test execution and how many passed or failed. is it possible in that way?

Comment: yes it is possible.